# Programming NodeMCU : connect PIR Sensor to RST Pin

Tags: arduino, sensors, esp8266, nodemcu

I use a PIR Sensor & NodeMCU ESP8266 Amica.
I program NodeMCU on the Arduino IDE.
I connected the sensor's output to the RST pin on my NodeMCU. So, when the PIR detect a movement, the output will be HIGH and so the NodeMCU will reboot. I tested my code by uploading the arduino's sketch to the NodeMCU, everything is fine. But, if I disconnect and reconnect the NodeMCU to my computer, the sensor doesn't seem working... The setup is executed but when I create movements in front of the PIR sensor, nothing is happening...

The question is, why ?
When I upload the sketch to the NodeMCU, everything work, but when I disconnect and reconnect (or when I plug the NodeMCU on an alimentation), nothing work...
Thank's for reeding me, I hope you'll found an answer ;)

Code (post request to a php script on setup), there is just the setup function, the loop function is empty :

```
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
Serial.println(ESP.getResetReason());
HTTPClient http;
http.begin("PHP_SCRIPT");
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.POST("message=Hello, from ESP8266"); 
http.writeToStream(&Serial);
http.end();
```

PIR Sensor = http://4tronix.co.uk/store/index.php?rt=product/product&keyword=pir&category_id=0&product_id=135

Comment: Ok, I tested again and again and now I think I have the answer : it's the PIR Sensor who is everytime sending a HIGH signal, so the NodeMCU reset the  first time but after, nothing happen, it's logic. But I don't know why the sensor send a HIGH signal only when after the sketch has been uploaded by the Arduino IDE